# gh-pages not publishing what's wrong

Tags: git, github, publish

I am totally new to GitHub and my purpose of joining is to use the GitHub-pages feature.i recently create a site and want to publish it using gt-pages.
and let me know you what steps actually I have taken to do this.

```
       1.I create new repo name myportfolio.github.io 
       2.and then I initialize it with a readme and change the master 
          branch to gh-pages.
       3.and make the gt-pages branch.
       4.and the default branch is gh-pages instead of master. and I update 
         it.
       5.then I go back to code.
       6. I upload all the files of my site.
       7.then I commit changes
       8.it processes my files.
```

and in the end, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jp0B.png)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give us link to your repo

Comment: @ArtemSolovev yes, sure here it is.
https://github.com/DarthVedar89/myarticle

Answer (score 0):

First, it is gh-branch, not gt-branch.

Second, make sure to go to the right URL:  `https://github.com/username/reponame`.
See this [tutorial for illustration](https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223).

For a [project page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/):

> Project Pages sites are available in the following locations after they're built:
>
> A Project Pages site for a personal account is available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`.